# mysql join tables query

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables job and dn (layout  below) and would like to join the tables

if i use

```
SELECT  part, description ,
        GROUP_CONCAT(job_number ORDER BY job_number desc) AS job_numbers,
        SUM(qty_ordered) as qty_ordered FROM  job
    where  type = 'part'
    GROUP BY  part
```

I get (part,description,job_numbers,qty_ordered) but would like to join tables to include qty del and delivery note numbers as output (below).  how would I do this

thanks

```
Job
+---------+---------+-----+----------+-----+-----+----------+-----+
|joblineid|jobitemid| type|job_number|part |descr|qty_ordred|note |
+---------+---------+-----+----------+-----+-----+----------+-----+
| 1       | 10      | part| 1        |part1|desc1|     33   |null |
| 2       | 11      | part| 1        |part2|desc2|     566  |null |
| 3       | 20      | part| 2        |part1|desc1|     423  |null |
| 4       | 21      | part| 2        |part2|desc2|     777  |null |
| 5       | 22      | part| 2        |part3|desc3|     6666 |null |
| 6       | 30      | part| 3        |part4|desc4|     1000 |null |
| 7       | 31      | note| 3        |null |null |     null |anote|
+---------+---------+-----+----------+-----+-----+----------+-----+  


dn
+--------+---------+----+----------+--------------+-----+-----+-------+
|dnlineid|jobitemid|type|job_number|delnote_number|part |descr|qty_del| 
+--------+---------+----+----------+-- -----------+-----+-----+-------+
| 1      |  10     |part| 1        | 1            |part1|desc1|30     |     
| 2      |  20     |part| 2        | 2            |part1|desc1|16     |    
| 3      |  21     |part| 2        | 3            |part2|desc2|800    |     
| 4      |  22     |part| 2        | 4            |part3|desc3|6000   |     
| 5      |  10     |part| 1        | 5            |part1|desc1|500    |    
+--------+---------+----+----------+--------------+-----+-------+-----+  




output
+-----+--------+-------------+--------------+--------------+----------+
|part | desc   | job_numbers | delnote_num | qty_ordred   | qty_del  | 
+-----+--------+-------------+--------------+--------------+----------+
|part1| desc1  | 1,2         |   1,2,5      |     456      |   546    |   
|part2| desc2  | 1,2         |   3          |     1343     |   800    |
|part3| desc3  | 2           |   4          |     6666     |   6000   |
|part4| desc4  | 3           |   null       |     1000     |   null   |
+-----+--------+-------------+--------------+--------------+----------+
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL? Also, could you please input your table structures as DDL (`CREATE TABLE blah (...);`) and your table data as DML (`INSERT INTO TABLE blah VALUES (...);`) - it makes life much easier for those trying to assist you. Help us to help you! There are a few articles on how to ask questions here on my profile - you might want to look? p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```
SELECT  a.part,
        a.description AS "desc",
        a.job_numbers
        dn.delnote_number,
        a.qty_ordered,
        dn.qty_del
    FROM ( SELECT  part, description, jobitemid
                GROUP_CONCAT(job_number ORDER BY job_number desc) AS job_numbers,
                SUM(qty_ordered) as qty_ordered FROM  job
            where  type = 'part'
            GROUP BY  part
         ) AS a
    LEFT JOIN dn  USING(jobitemid)
```

OP says that this is the result:

```
part        desc     job_numbers    delnote_num     qty_ordered      qty_del

"part1"     "desc1"    "2,1"       "1"              "456"            "30"
"part3"     "desc3"    "2"         "4"              "6666"           "6000"
"part1"     "desc1"    "2,1"       "5"              "456"            "500"
"part2"     "desc2"    "2,1"       NULL             "1343"           NULL
"part4"     "desc4"    "3"         NULL             "1000"           NULL
```

Comment: What does the derived table get?